# Setting up a rest service using gradle

Tags: java, rest, gradle

I am attempting to use gradle for the first time but having difficulties creating a simple project skeleton from which I can work on.

[image: Project Structure]

Here's my build.gradle content

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'backend'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
war{
    baseName = 'api'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Everything builds fine and runs fine using the following commands

```
gradle clean build
```

and

```
gradle bootRun
```

However, I don't see any context path I can use

```
2018-05-27 20:32:27.107  INFO 8049 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-27 20:32:27.108  INFO 8049 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-05-27 20:32:27.129  INFO 8049 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-27 20:32:27.129  INFO 8049 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-27 20:32:27.231  INFO 8049 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-27 20:32:27.271  INFO 8049 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-05-27 20:32:27.275  INFO 8049 --- [           main] com.initiator.Application                : Started Application in 1.976 seconds (JVM running for 2.342)
2018-05-27 20:32:41.119  INFO 8049 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-05-27 20:32:41.119  INFO 8049 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-05-27 20:32:41.133  INFO 8049 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 14 ms
```

I tried the following urls

```
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/api
http://localhost:8080/api/greeting
```

None of them worked and I get

```
    Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to specify base scan packages (argument of the SpringBootApplication annotation to use packages which are not below the Application's package. For more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Comment: I did that, I followed this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
The Application class has the SpringBootApplication annotation and the controller has a RestController annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot scans the packages of your Application class and its subpackages for annotations by default. In your code structure overview it seems like you have your Application located in `com.initiator` and your entities and controllers in `com.controller` or  `com.entity`. Entities or controllers in these both packages will not be scanned with the default behaviour when you just annotate your main class with `@SpringBootApplication`.

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Make your entity and controller packages subpackages of your Application class.
2. Specify the `scanBasePackages` property to include the controller and entity packages which are no subpackages of your Application class, e.g. `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.entity", "com.controller" })`.

I would advice to stick with the first option and stick with the default behaviour (less work for you, clear for others where to search for your annotated classes).

Comment: Thank you! that worked, I used the first option, moved the Application.java class up a directory and it scanned.
I have added api in the gradle.build file as a context path but it's not working.
how can i change my url so I can use localhost:8080/api/greeting instead?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri

Comment: Thank you! adding server.servlet.contextPath=/api
to src>main>resources>application.properties file did the trick

Comment: If you just want Spring REST to be served on `/api` use `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api`.

Comment: I tried spring.data.rest-basePath but that didn't work. Had to use server.servlet.contextPath. Not sure why

Comment: My bad, I misread your information. `spring.data.rest.basePath` is for RestRepositories, you have custom controllers which are not affected by this property on default.